# How can I wait for the async done before running a statement on vue?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

My vue component like this :

```
<template> 
    ...
    <v-dialog
        :ref="..."
        v-model="..."
        :return-value.sync="..."
    >

        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-btn color="success" dark v-on="on" @click="showDatepicker(id)">Show datepicker</v-btn>
        </template>
        ...
        <v-date-picker v-model="..." scrollable :picker-date.sync="pickerDate">
        ...
    </v-dialog>
    ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  watch: { 
    pickerDate: async function(newval) {

        let a = moment(newval, "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth()
        for (var i = 1; i <= a ; i++) {
           ...
        }
    },
  },
  methods: {  
      showDatepicker: async function(id) {
        await this.getDataById({id:id});
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

when the user clicks the show datepicker button, it will call watch pickerDate and showDatepicker method at once

before running the statement in watch pickerDate, I want to wait for aysnc / ajax `this.getDataById({id: id});` finish first

how do i do that?

I actually only want to use pickerDate, but I can't send ID via pickerDate. so I use watch and method

Note :

The datepicker in loop

I using vuetify

Answer (score 0):

In the date-picker tag remove the pickerDate and its data property and use event  instead

```
<v-date-picker v-model="..." scrollable @update:picker-date="pickerUpdate($event, id)">


<script>
...

methods: { 
    pickerDate: async function(newval, id) {
         await showDatepicker(id)
        let a = moment(newval, "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth()
        for (var i = 1; i <= a ; i++) {
           ...
        }
    },
  },
  {  
      showDatepicker: async function(id) {
        await this.getDataById({id:id});
    }
  },
...
</script>
```

Comment: You are great. Thank you